# How to duplicate Magento CMS pages and content blocks for additional language scopes

Tags: magento, content-management-system, scopes

I neeed to find out if it is possible to duplicate a content block or page in Magento much in the same way that you can with products?

For example, I can create a product in (English) and then select an alternative language scope (Italian) and paste the text in for the Italian version.

That is intuitive.

Is this possible for CMS pages and Blocks? It does not appear to be - but maybe I am missing something?

I navigate to CMS > Pages and select a page to edit, it just looks to offer the ability to change the language allocation (not duplicate it for alternative scopes).

Comment: there is extension available for that http://shreejiinfosys.co.in/index.php/duplicate-cms-page-block.html  .  Note : I am not promoting this extension just found in google result and and its cheap among other extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to duplicate CMS blocks within the Magento admin.

There are a number of extensions that will add this function or alternatively ones that allow you to export, amend in CSV and then import to create the duplicate pages or static blocks quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The CMS Blocks in Magento 2.x are stored in 2 tables:

- cms_block
- cms_block_store

You can export the cms_block table directly from the mysql db and change what ever you want with an external editor like open-office calc (in my opinion better than excell for export to csv) delete teh column with the id and import again.

If you are implementing a multiple website/store magento then you will need to also export/import the cms_page_store with the correct id's of the block and the store